# How to start a string using BATCH

Tags: string, batch-file

I'm trying to make a program that will search google for what the user had typed in to i created this:

`@echo off 
set "str1=www.google.co.uk/search?q=" 
echo What shall i do? 
set /p Input= 
set "str2=%str1%%Input%" 
Start "str2" 
Pause 
:END`

The problem is that when is starts "str2" it just opens a new command prompt window called "str2" but i want it to run what "str2" is, which is a google url, how can i make that happen? Also, if i entered two words like "elephant babies" into the input then how will i make it realize that i want it to search for "elephant babies" and not just "elephant"?

Help appreciated

-Atlas

Comment: `Start "%str2%" `  - looks like missed percent signs.

Comment: Ah yes, you're right. I added percentage signs and that didn't work so i took away the quotation marks and that has done the trick: `start %str2%` However it will only search for the first word still and ignore the second one. So i  type in "cute babies" and it only searches for "babies" and ignores "cute" :/

Comment: this is because you need your url URI encoded.replace blank space with `%%20` in batch or with `%20` if it is called directly from command line.

Comment: Sorry, i'm new to the whole batch programming, What do you mean "replace blank space with %%20" ?? Do you mean like this?:        `@echo off
color 2
set "str1=www.google.co.uk/search?q="
echo What shall i do?
set /p Input=
set "str2=%str1%%Input%"
Start %str2%
echo %str2%
%%20
Pause
:END`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your code extended for a valid Google query (not complete for all possible queries):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "SearchUrl=https://www.google.co.uk/search?q="
set /p "Input=Enter search query: "
set "SearchUrl=%SearchUrl%!Input: =+!"
set "SearchUrl=!SearchUrl:"=%%22!"
start "Google Search" "%SearchUrl%"
endlocal
pause
```

The first line after `set /p` concatenates predefined string with user entered string whereby each space is replaced by a plus sign as necessary for a Google query.

In the next line all double quotes in entered search query are replaced by `%22` as needed for a Google query.

Running this batch file with entering `"Stack Overflow"` results in starting default browser with the URL:

```
https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22Stack+Overflow%22
```

For details about `setlocal` referencing variables with exclamation mark instead of percent sign for delayed expansion and how those replaces in the entered strings work, open a command prompt window, enter `set /?`, hit key <kbd>RETURN</kbd> or <kbd>ENTER</kbd> and read the help output now in console window for command **set**.

Executing a Windows command or Windows console application with parameter `/?` usually results in getting a brief description for this command / console application displayed in command prompt window.